# Angular <img [src] (error) not working

Tags: angular, image, url

So what im trying to do, if the image url is broken, i want to try another url, both url are dynamic, i only get the id of the image from the api.

I have no idea what is wrong why it is not working - i checked if i get the id first if its not empty, it is not, i do get the id correctly.

html file

[image]

ts.file

[image]

Instead showing the image, here is the response i get as string

```
<img id="player" style="width: 14.4vw;" [src]="https://static.hltv.org//images/playerprofile/bodyshot/compressed/"+post. 
  id+".png" (error)="setDefaultPic(post.id)">
```

Comment: Try `[src]="'https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/bodyshot/compressed/' + post.
  id + '.png'"`.

Comment: i know there is a typo in url with double // after hltv.org in the first screenshot, the issue remains same.

Comment: @ConnorsFan the response i got now `src="https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/bodyshot/compressed/8446.png"` image is still broken, it seems doesnt go for (error)

Comment: In your `changeImage`, you're setting `this.pic`, but I can't see where you're using that...

Comment: @user184994 in (error) ?

Comment: @Dovydas So your `(error)` function which calls the `changeImage` function sets `this.pic`, but what are you doing with `this.pic` once it's been set? You're never changing the URL of the image. Can you create a StackBlitz or something similar with your code in so we can reproduce?

Comment: @user184994 that is actually true, you opened my eyes now, how can i tell then where to use this.pic? not sure how to do it...

Comment: Something like `(error)="$event.target.src = getErrorImageUrl(post.id)"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan @user184994 thank you both - helped a lot  `event.target.src = "https://static.hltv.org/images/playerprofile/thumb/"+id+"/400.jpeg?v=2";` this works